# Why does this format specification not work on a TimeSpan?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

On a test overview, I am displaying a duration with the following expression:

```
= IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!EndTime.Value), " - ", 
    String.Format("{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", Fields!EndTime.Value - Fields!StartTime.Value))
```

It displays the duration of a test or `-` if no endtime was stated. In the preview, the Duration looks OK:

> 01:23:45

This is as expected, see also [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fOiwIy).
But when I Deploy my report, it look like this in the browser:

> 01:23:45.6780000

How is that possible? (A quick solution would probably be just `Left`ing the string, but I am curious why it is not displayed as expected).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Even when the TimeSpan contains fractions of a second, I only see something like "01:23:45".

Comment: Note: Always use `If` instead of `IIF` in .NET

Comment: @MattWilko somehow dotnetfiddle does not support IIf (I'm new to the VB.NET side of dotnetfiddle) so I did it with an if to stay somewhat true my solution. I am using it in reporting services (with the advantage of short circuiting :). )

Comment: @MattWilko Oh, yes, you are right. I thought you stated it the other way around, sorry. I need to use IIF in reporting services because you can only enter one expression. Multiple lines, anonymous functions etc. are not allowed as expression.

Comment: Using the `If` *Operator* would just be one expression just like your fiddle. (I am not talking about the `If` *Statement*). Just humour me and change your `IIF` to `If` - You'll thank me one day :-)

Comment: @MattWilko I agree that `If` is usually preferable to `IIf`, but that isn't the cause of the problem here, right?

Comment: @MattWilko unfortunately, `If` does not work as expression in Reporting Services.